# jolt transformation - array array inside apache nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

my attempts

**Input** :

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "group": {
        "queueId": "fila1",
        "mediaType": "message1"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "metric": "oInteracting1",
          "stats": {
            "count": 1
          },
          "truncated": false
        },
        {
          "metric": "oWaiting1",
          "stats": {
            "count": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": {
        "queueId": "fila2",
        "mediaType": "message2"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "metric": "oInteracting2",
          "stats": {
            "count": 8
          },
          "truncated": false
        },
        {
          "metric": "oWaiting2",
          "stats": {
            "count": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": {
        "queueId": "fila3",
        "mediaType": "message3"
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "metric": "oInteracting3",
          "stats": {
            "count": 1
          },
          "truncated": false
        },
        {
          "metric": "oWaiting3",
          "stats": {
            "count": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Unsuccessful attempt** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "results": {
        "*": {
          "@group.queueId": "[&].queueid",
          "@group.mediaType": "[&].mediatype",
          "data": {
            "*": {
              "@metric": "[&3].metric1",
              "@stats.count": "[&3].metric1_count"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Unsuccessful Output** :

```json
[
  {
    "queueid": "fila1",
    "mediatype": "message1",
    "metric1": [
      "oInteracting1",
      "oWaiting1"
    ],
    "metric1_count": [
      1,
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "queueid": "fila2",
    "mediatype": "message2",
    "metric1": [
      "oInteracting2",
      "oWaiting2"
    ],
    "metric1_count": [
      8,
      0
    ]
  },
  {
    "queueid": "fila3",
    "mediatype": "message3",
    "metric1": [
      "oInteracting3",
      "oWaiting3"
    ],
    "metric1_count": [
      1,
      0
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected output** :

```json
[
  {
    "queueid": "fila1",
    "mediatype": "message1",
    "oInteracting1": 1,
    "oWaiting1": 0
  },
  {
    "queueid": "fila2",
    "mediatype": "message2",
    "oInteracting1": 8,
    "oWaiting1": 0
  },
  {
    "queueid": "fila3",
    "mediatype": "message3",
    "oInteracting3": 1,
    "oWaiting3": 0
  }
]
```

Also trying to add the condition

```json
"data": {"\*": { "stats.count": "metric"}}
```

but it didn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *recursively* match within the **`stats`** object such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "results": {
        "*": {
          "@group.queueId": "[&].queueid",
          "@group.mediaType": "[&].mediatype",
          "data": {
            "*": {
              "stats": {
                "@count": "[&4].@2,metric" // traverses : and { ( 2 levels ) to reach upto its original level within the JSON
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: 100%. thank you very much. I'm studying to improve my knowledge

Comment: Goodnight. I managed to post right away: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75639073/apache-nifi-jolt-transformation-root-array-values-without-keys